# Get origin of Android Market link after install

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any way to get the origin of a link to an app on Android Market after the app is installed?

Let's say I have three different web pages that link to the same Android Market app, can I get the origin of the link after the app is installed so I can use it for statistics and such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using google analytics with in your android app it should be possible to get the referrer to your app. Read this [introduction](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#android-market-tracking) to google analytics to see how it is done.

You have to link to your app with a special referrer link. There is also a link generator on the google analytics page.

You have to follow this steps to add referral tracking to your android app.

1. Add this snippet to your manifest
   file:

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
   ```

   android:exported="true">
2. Now you have to integrate Google
   analytics like it is explained on
   the page above.
3. Create Referral links for all three sites and link with them to your app.